# My emacs company mode won't work with python. I use doom emacs. I have company mode and ivy in my init.el. I have flycheck enabled in python

Tags: auto-complete-mode, doom, popup

```
:completion
       company           ; the ultimate code completion backend
       ;;helm              ; the *other* search engine for love and life
       ;;ido               ; the other *other* search engine...
       (ivy +fonts +ivyposframe)               ; a search engine for love and life
```

I use Emacs version 27.1 and Doom version 2.0.9 and Python version 3.9.1. What do I do to get the completion popups working again.

Comment: Define *"won't work"*. The question is unclear.

Comment: "popups working again"--so they worked at some point? Can you describe your setup when they worked and what changed since then?